# Create ad-hoc network using c# from my application

Tags: c#, adhoc

I want to create ad-hoc network using c# in my application automaticaly without force the user to make it using windows and users can connect to this network using my application

Comment: This is a "I want a pony" question.  Write a web app.

Comment: What would be the purpose of your network? What are the users going to communicate with each other?

Comment: laptops to send information like text or images

Answer (score 0):

you can that by Peer-to-Peer API.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371704(VS.85).aspx

but, that APIs are native. can't use direct from C#, you can access API by P/Invoke.